# Javascript, counters and real-time applications

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm currently working on a game and i have decided to go with javascript to make a prototype. During the development i noticed that i use a lot of counters in this way:

```
function update() {
   for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       // do stuff
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Keeping in mind that this is a real time application so the update function is executed almost 60 times per second, we can say that i'm creating a lot of variables. I was wondering how that piece of code would affect performance (does the javascript engine make some optimization here?) and how the garbage collector behaves in this situation (i don't even know how the GC manages primitive types...).

For now i changed the code to look like this:

```
var counters = {};

function update() {
   for(counters['taskA'] = 0; counters['taskA'] < n; counters['taskA']++) {
       // do stuff
   }

   for(counters['taskB'] = 0; counters['taskB'] < m; counters['taskB']++) {
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Does this code make any difference?

Comment: I believe that the best thing to do in this situation would be to test both methods using [jsPref](http://jsperf.com/) to test both approaches. If you offered some more code I would had created the tests for you. But since this is a prototype, I feel that best readability would be best for now and later optimization.

Comment: More likely than not your change decreased performance.  In your original, `i` never went out of scope, so your second loop just re-used it.  Adding multiple array lookups couldn't possibly have _increased_ performance.  Second, what are you talking about JVM?  Javascript is not Java, there's no JVM involved.  And you can always use http://jsperf.com/ to test javascript performance.

Comment: @waxen yeah, i meant javascript engine, not JVM. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any significant performance difference. However, the `counters` variable will not be garbage collected if its on the global scope. It will only get GCed when it goes out of scope so if its within another function that will be mostly fine.

On your first example the `i` variables definitely get GCed as there within the `update` function.